# Code Igniter not letting me load multiple libraries

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am building an application using the Code Igniter framework in which I have built many different libraries of which I load into the controllers they are needed in.

When I try and load multiple libraries into my 'home' controller I get the following message:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Home::$messaging

Filename: controllers/home.php

Line Number: 73


Fatal error: Call to a member function getMessages() on a non-object in /home/totalcar/public_html/application/controllers/home.php on line 73
```

I have never encountered this error before as I have had controllers before loading multiple libraries no problem. It seems to think that the messaging library doesn't exist or is not being loaded.
I have ensured that the filenames for the libraries have a capital first letter, as do the class declarations and this doesn't seem to make any difference.

I load my libraries seperately as shown below.
 (Please note I have removed lots of irrelevant code from the controller to make it easier to read here)

```
public function index() {
        ...         

        //Load Helpers
        $this->load->helper('menu');
        $this->load->helper('layout');          

        //Load Libraries
        $this->load->library('pusher');         
        $this->load->library('test');           

        //Load User Details
        $data['userid'] = $this->session->userdata('userid');

        $data['modules'] = getModules($this->layout_model, $this->socialmedia_model);

        //Build Menu
        $data['menuItems'] = buildMenu($this->session->userdata('user_group_id'), $this->config);
        $data['firstName'] = $this->session->userdata('firstName');


        //Unread Messages 
        $options = array(
            'userId'  => $data['userid'],
            'opened' => 0
        );
        $this->load->library('messaging', $options);            
        $data['unreadMessages'] = $this->messaging->getMessages();
        $data['mailIcon'] = (empty($data['unreadMessages'])) ? "mailButton.png" : "mailButtonUnread.png";
```

Can anybody offer any guidance here?
Thanks

Edit: here is my library code:

```
<?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Messaging extends CI_Controller {

    private $options;
    private $unreadMessages;
    public $mailIcon;

    function __construct($options) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('messaging_model');
        $this->load->model('staff_model');
        $this->options = $options;
    }

    function getMessages() {
        $unreadMessages = $this->messaging_model->getMessages($this->options);
        $this->unreadMessagesReturn = array();
        $mailIcon = (empty($unreadMessages)) ? "mailButton.png" : "mailButtonUnread.png";
        if(!empty($unreadMessages)) {
            foreach($unreadMessages as $message) {
                $fromUserDetails = $this->staff_model->getStaffMemberDetails($message['from_id']);
                if((isset($fromUserDetails['profile_image_small'])) && $fromUserDetails['profile_image_small'] != "") {
                    $profileImageSmall = $this->config->base_url() . "images/profileImages/" . $fromUserDetails['profile_image_small']; 
                } else {
                    $profileImageSmall = $this->config->base_url() . "images/noImage.png";
                }
                $name = $fromUserDetails[0]['first_name'] . " " . $fromUserDetails[0]['last_name'];
                $dateSent = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($message['time_sent']));
                $messageTruncated = substr($message['message'], 0, 70) . "...";
                $this->unreadMessagesReturn[] = array(
                    'fromPic'          => $profileImageSmall,
                    'fromName'         => $name,
                    'subject'          => $message['subject'],
                    'message'          => $message['message'],
                    'messageTruncated' => $messageTruncated,
                    'dateSent'         => $dateSent
                );
            }
            return $this->unreadMessagesReturn;
        }
    }       
}
```

?>

Comment: What settings do you have in `application\config\config.php` for `subclass_prefix`, the default is `MY_` and whats your library filename?

Comment: Try using this code `$CI = & get_instance(); $CI->load->library('messaging', $options)`

Comment: Why did you think that multiple libraries is the problem? Shouldn't the PHP error be much more informative? What's the code on/before line 73 of `/home/totalcar/public_html/application/controllers/home.php`?

Comment: Can i see your library Code

Comment: Ok I have added the library code. Also, line 73 is $data['unreadMessages'] = $this->messaging->getMessages(); as shown above

Comment: Are you sure that's a library? it's extending the default controller `CI_Controller`, make sure it's stored in the `application/libraries` folder and try removing `extends CI_Controller`, you can then use the code @Jigar posted to access the CI info/ methods from within the library.

Comment: Hi,Thanks that worked! I forgot I didn't need to extend the CI_Controller class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to sort this problem by not extending the CI_Controller as shown above then including the $CI = & get_instance(); line and accessing the CI library methods and models using that.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem loading multiple libraries on `__construct` method.

I handled this by loading them individualy. Loading each one inside the specific Controller's method that needed it.

Example:

```
class S extends CI_Controller {
   public function __construct() {
      // -- notice that there are not loadings here
      parent::__construct();
   }
   public function index() {       
      $this->load->view('vista_v');
   }
   public function registro( $accion = 'l', $parametros = '' ){
      $this->load->library('../controllers/analistas_c'); 
      $this->analistas_c->registro( $accion, $parametros );
   }
   public function tarea( $accion = 'l', $parametros = '' ){
      $this->load->library('../controllers/tareas_c');
      $this->tareas_c->registro( $accion, $parametros );
   }
}
```

This is working as expected now.

Answer (score -1):

```
In controller add constructor method
public function __construct()
{
//Here you will load all libraries and models files
}
```